# Using html forms to change java script fields without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, forms

K everything I find on this requires jquery but I want a way so I can type stuff into text boxes and sliders then submit it (preferably without changing the page) and have the forms data modify java script variables without having to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that will use the values provided by the user in the form to update the JS variables as you want. Then you just need to call this function from a button's `onclick` handler:

```
<script>
    var myVarToUpdate = "test";

    function update() {
        // find the input element by ID and assign its value to `myVarToUpdate`
        myVarToUpdate = document.getElementById("someText").value;
    }
</script>

<form>
    <input id="someText" value="" />
    <button type="button" onclick="update()">Update</button>
</form>
```

This way the form will not be submitted at all, i.e. the page won't reload. Actually, you even do not need a proper `<form>` in this case.

Comment: where do I place the onsubmit event/attricbute? is it in the submit button tag?

Comment: In my example, `<form>` had `onsubmit` attribute. The contents of the attribute is basically JS code. In this case, it's a call to `update()` function (and a `return` statement to prevent form submission).

Comment: Alternatively, as you do not really need a proper form in this case, you could call `update()` from the button's `onclick`: `<button type="button" onclick="update()">Update</button>`.

Comment: I've updated my example to use the second variant with `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically NEED the submit functionality you can do the following

Make your HTML input elements name a jsvar viar a data attribute like so :

```
  <input data-jsvar="myvar" />
```

In your JS, put `onChange` handlers on these input elements:

```
  function changeVar (ev) {
    var v = this.getAttribute ('data-jsvar');
    if (v && v in window) {
      window[v] = this.value;
      console.log (v + ' = ' + window[v]);  // for debug
    }
  }


  [].forEach.call (document.querySelectorAll ('[data-jsvar]'), function (inp) {
      inp.addEventListener ('change', changeVar, false);
      window[inp.getAttribute ('data-jsvar')] = inp.value; // optional init for var
  });
```

This neatly separates JS from HTML and makes for easy expansion by just adding html elements. See the demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/zvhpc/